# Prometheus ratio with division not working

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I'm trying to calculate de % of request errors in a period of time.
If I'm not wrong this should give me 1:

```
sum(sum_over_time(http_client_requests{env=~"env"}))/sum(sum_over_time(http_client_requests{env=~"env"}))
```

But I'm getting a random number over 200. I think I'm getting the sum of all the 1's, should I then use the average or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: could you provide some sample values of `http_client_requests` ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're getting the sum of all the ones and if you replace "sum" for "avg" (like you've suggested) you'll get "1" as result instead.

Note: your promql expression isn't correct, the range vector selectors (something like: [5h], [1d], etc) are missing in the "sum_over_time" functions.

Comment: I usually select in grafana a time range so I have not to set it manually

Comment: I think it started working when I added ``[$__range]`` to both ``sum_over_time``

Comment: What do you mean by "started working"? Are you talking about the time range selected in Grafana? Yes, you need to add [$__range] to the expression. Or are you talking about the original question (why are you "getting a random number over 200").

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, it didn't work either. Finally I had to use some transformations to calculate the global avg of failed requests